# how to insert sum of the columns in select query in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a select query and my column type is text but then I type cast it into integer using the query

```
 select case
   when fti.status!='not signed' then  1::integer
   when ftrq.is_the_site_cleared = '1' then 1::integer 
   when ftrq.is_the_site_cleared = '0' then 0::integer
   end as is_the_site_cleared from fti join ftrq on ftrq.fulcrum_parent_id = fti.fulcrum_id
```

I do have number of columns like this and want to have a total for them as last value in the column which may be like sum(is_the_site_cleared ) at the bottom.  How can I achieve this? I am using postgresql 9.3 which says sum(text) function doesn't exist. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select sum(is_the_site_cleared) from (select case
       when fti.status!='not signed' then  1
       when ftrq.is_the_site_cleared = '1' then 1 
       when ftrq.is_the_site_cleared = '0' then 0
       end as is_the_site_cleared from fti join ftrq on 
       ftrq.fulcrum_parent_id = fti.fulcrum_id) res;
```